# IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am setting up the Inn-App billing from Google play in my LibGDX based Android app.

**Scenario** : I have bought the test product "**android.test.purchased**" successfully and I have not Consumed it. I have not consumed it because it can be bought only once and I have disabled the buy button for that test product. Till this everything is fine.

**Issue** : Now when I re open the again for 2nd time. I got an alert saying that "Failed to query inventory: IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed".

**Question :**
I expect my product can be bought only once and hence I have not consumed it. Will that be a problem while querying for the inventory in onCreate().

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
```

### Code

```
private void iabSetup() { 

// load game data
loadData();

String base64EncodedPublicKey = "Key";

Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished."); 
        if (!result.isSuccess()) { 
            complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
            return;
        } 
        if (mHelper == null) return; 
        Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");  
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);

    }
});
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        } 
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful."); 

        // Do we have the additional 1 life?
        Purchase life1Purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_1_Life);
        life1Purchased = (life1Purchase != null);
        Log.d(TAG, "User life1Purchased : " + life1Purchased);

};  


public void onAdd1lifeButtonClicked() {
    if (!mHelper.subscriptionsSupported()) {
        complain("Subscriptions not supported on your device yet. Sorry!");
        return;
    }  
    Log.d(TAG, "Launching purchase flow for infinite gas subscription."); 

    if (busy) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Can't buy item. So busy yet"); 
        return;
    }  
    try {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        busy = true;
                        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(AndroidLauncher.this, SKU_1_Life, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, payloadString);
                }
        }).start(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "buyItem Exception: " + e); 
    } 
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: " + purchase);

        // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain("Error purchasing: " + result); 
            return;
        }
        if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
            complain("Error purchasing. Authenticity verification failed."); 
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

        if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_1_Life)) { 
            Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is SKU_1_Life.");   
            busy = false;
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to this yet ?